# SIGSEGV Fault with my program

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, segmentation-fault

IDE
Codeblocks
mingw32-make 3.82.90

Below is the call stack for my program

> Call stack
>  0 0x45cb6b std::string::assign(std::string const&) ()
>   (??:??)
>  1 0x1 ?? () (??:??)
>  2 0xf72ac0    ?? () (??:??)
>  **3
>   0x402332  Shop::initItem(this=0xf72778)
>   (C:\Users\Hethann\Desktop\Codeblock_Source\Coffee\shop.cpp:107)**
>   
>  4 0x4020e3   Shop::initMenu(this=0xf72778)
>   (C:\Users\Hethann\Desktop\Codeblock_Source\Coffee\shop.cpp:68)
>  5
>   0x402093  Shop::initShop(this=0xf72778)
>   (C:\Users\Hethann\Desktop\Codeblock_Source\Coffee\shop.cpp:54)
>  6
>   0x401f58  Shop::Shop(this=0xf72778)
>   (C:\Users\Hethann\Desktop\Codeblock_Source\Coffee\shop.cpp:46)
>  7
>   0x4013c1  main()
>   (C:\Users\Hethann\Desktop\Codeblock_Source\Coffee\main.cpp:10)

Problem occurred at #3.Following are the code snippets of the related parts

## 1. Method that is causing the SIGSEGV Fault

```
bool Shop::initItem()
{
    int count = 0, tempPrice;
    std::string input;
    std::stringstream tempSTRM;
    std::vector <Item>::iterator itemITR = menu.items.begin();
    Item tempITM;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Input item name for item[" << count+1 << "]\t:\t";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        if(input == "0")
            break;

        tempITM.itemName = input;

        std::cout << "Input the price for the item[" << count+1 << "]\t:\t";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);

        tempSTRM.str(input);
        tempSTRM >> tempPrice;
        tempITM.price = tempPrice;

        menu.items.push_back(tempITM);

        tempITM = *itemITR; //this line is causing the problem
        std::cout << tempITM.itemName << "\t" << tempITM.price << "\n";

        itemITR++;
        count++;

    }while(input !="0");

    return false;
}
```

## 2. Menu Struct

```
struct MenuItems
{
    std::string menuName;
    std::vector <Item> items;
};
typedef struct MenuItems Menu;
```

## 3. Item Struct

```
    struct Item
{
    std::string itemName;
    int price;

    bool promoStatus;
    double promoDiscount;
};
typedef struct Item Item;
```

## 4 Main (Only that part of the code is related to whatever I'm building now)

```
#include <windows.h> //leftover code from previous experiment
#include <tchar.h>   //leftover code from previous experiment

#include "CoffeeShop.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Shop* CoffeeShop = new Shop();
//Other leftover codes
    return 0;
}
```

My intention : Is to get the output of whatever I'm trying to push in (As I'm building the project so once other parts are ready I can confidently produce an output.)

Since this induces a SIGSEGV problem, so my current idea won't work. Tried it with putting a pointer object Item and get access to itemITR but it doesn't work too. Anyone can shed light on what I was wrong on (ideologically) and how should I do it?

--Edit--

```
Shop::Shop()
{
    if(!initShop())
        std::cout << "Object creation succeeded!\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Object creation failed!\n";
}

bool Shop::initShop()
{
    if(!initMenu())
    {
        std::cout << "Object creation succeeded!\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Object creation failed!\n";
        return true;
    }
}

bool Shop::initMenu()
{
    if(!initItem())
    {
        std::cout << "Object Creation succeeded!\n";
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Object creation failed!\n";
        return true;
    }
}
```

The flow -> Shop constructor calls initShop then initShop calls initMenu, initMenu calls initItem

Shop-> initShop -> initMenu -> initItem

--EDIT 2--

Solved. Added

```
itemITR = menu.items.begin();
```

after the line

```
menu.items.push_back(tempITM);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show how you call `initItem()`.

Comment: `Shop* CoffeeShop = new Shop();`  C++ is not Java.  All you need is: `Shop CoffeeShop;`

Comment: @MichaelWalz Have added the "calling structure".

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I was thinking along the lines of maybe making a lot of shops so I placed a pointer Object so it's easier to make an array of shops but that may change as the project goes along. *Just a small side project for me*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your iterator is initialized with a given vector:

```
std::vector <Item>::iterator itemITR = menu.items.begin();
```

You then insert something in the vector:

```
    menu.items.push_back(tempITM);
```

This [might invalidate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) the iterator. So dereferencing it is UB and causes here the segfault

Comment: I tried to add menu.items.begin() after the menu.items.push_back(tempITM); it worked. Thanks for highlighting that. Never knew it would cause such behavior.